# Wifi on iMac Constantly Dropping

Tags: wireless-networking, imac

My late 2012 iMac has had constant issues with the wifi periodically disconnecting. I tried upgrading to OSX Mountain Lion but the issue still persists. My Linux and Windows Machines (that are right next to the iMac) have never had any issues with wifi dropping out. What could be the problem here?

I have attempted to search for solutions and there does seem to be quite a lot of stuff out there but none of the fixes that I've tried seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems with WiFi on my MacBook (Lion) (mine didn't even *recognized* the network) and did a lot of research on it. There are a couple of typical things suggested for solving issues like this. I did almost all of them and somehow the problem was solved, but I'm not sure which one worked! So, I just list them. Check either one of them and see if the issue is solved or not.

1. Go to System Preferences -> Network: **remove the WiFi interface from the left list and then add a new one.**
2. System Preferences -> Network: **Create a new location** (at the top) and use it for connecting. For some, this has solved the dropping problem.
3. Go to Network -> Advanced -> TCP/IP and click **Renew DHCP Lease**.
4. If neither of the above worked, this solution may solve it: [Resolving Stubborn Wi-Fi Connection Problems in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/11/30/resolving-stubborn-wi-fi-connection-problems-in-mac-os-x/). (Also, check the comments on the above site. Some have suggested other solutions.)

So, these were the things I can think of that may help solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

On an OS X system, you can view details on a WiFi connection from a [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28macOS%29) window using the command `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I`. You will see something like the following:

```
$ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
     agrCtlRSSI: -53
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -95
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station
     lastTxRate: 73
        maxRate: 72
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID: 94:44:52:5a:24:22
           SSID: Shire
            MCS: 7
        channel: 1
$
```

The `agrCtlRSSI` value is a measure of the signal strength - the "RSSI" stands for [received signal strength indication](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Rssi). The closer the number is to zero the stronger the signal; weaker signals are indicated by numbers closer to negative 100. The `agrCtlNoise` value provides an indicator of how [noisy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) the signal is; less negative values are better, so in the above example the -95 is not good, though the signal strength level is ok. The numbers may give you an indication of whether the iMac is experiencing some issue related to the Wi-Fi signal.

Or you might be experiencing a [problem I've encountered with a MacBook Pro laptop due to some neighbor's router using a different country code](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/wireless/conflicting-country-code/). Some routers will advertise a [country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code) in the information they provide to nearby wireless devices. Windows and Linux devices don't seem to have a problem if a router is advertising a country code that conflicts with a country code advertised by another nearby router, but Apple OS X systems may intermittently drop Wi-Fi connections in such situations. You can check for such a problem by running Apple's wireless diagnostic utility. To do so, click on the WiFi icon at the top of the screen while holding down the *option* key then select *Open Wireless Diagnostics*. If that is the source of the problem, you will see "Conflicting Country Codes" listed in the results summary. If you click on the "i" to see further information, you will be informed:

> Certain wireless routers have the ability to identify the country they
>   are designated to work in, this is called the Country Code. Wireless
>   routers should only be used in the country they were originally
>   obtained from. Failure to do so can result in performance and
>   reliability issues for nearby wireless clients.

You can also identify this problem by running the command `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s` - look in the "CC" column in the output. If you see any differing country codes that is likely the source of your problem and your [Wi-Fi connectivity will periodically drop due to the conflicting country codes](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/wireless/lost-connection/). I've found that I can turn Wi-Fi off and on to immediately restore WiFi connectivity, but unless you can track down the offending wireless router and get its owner to replace it, you may not be able to permanently resolve the problem with the iMac if that is the cause of the problem.

Even if your problem is due to some other issue running the wireless diagnostics utility that comes with OS X may identify the source of the problem or at least give you some useful information to aid in isolating the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because the channel of your wifi router is the same as other routers in your neighborhood.
follow the steps below and you will be sorted.

1. System preferences > advanced > WiFi > Delete your saved WiFi.
2. Delete all your saved WiFi passwords from the keychain
3. Go to the router setup from another computer AND CHANGE THE CHANNEL. For router with 2.4 Ghz band, set the channel to 3 or 4. For router with 5Ghz band, set the channel to 36 or 42. Some routers have both the bands. Change both.
4. Connect back to your router.

Thats it!

Comment: What does the keychain have to do with this?

Comment: It's a way of ensuring that the iMac cannot connect to those SSIDs again without prompting for a password.

Comment: "This could be happening because"...

Answer (score -1):

Having same issue with WiFi connectivity on a IMac 2011 w High Sierra... country code bs  prevents me to have a stable connection. ( I can see it is set on JP ) .
What if you don’t have a router ?  I’m connecting to wifi (direct) access point through MAC address.( user access account doesn’t have options , like a router)
Access point it’s on the building hallway outside of my apt .
Probably getting a  cable :)) provider but is not my intent .